# What's going on with my running toilet?

Tags: toilet

I have two toilets on my second floor. One will run occasionally after it is flushed until the second toilet is flushed. When the second toilet is flushed, the first stops running as soon as the valve is opened.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm guessing the momentarily decreased pressure when the second toilet flushes allows the first one's valve to seat. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

flushing the second toilet causes a sudden dip in supply pressure that allows the first to seal and once sealed there is no flow holding the valve open.

It sounds like the float valve needs a new button.

Comment: Does that mean that I would need to replace the whole float valve, or can I just replace that one part?

Comment: usually replacing the little rubber button is enough unless the seat is damaged. (these terms are parts of the valve not externally visible parts)